# how to allow cross-origin in [PHP]

Tags: php

I have 2 domains.

I try to open a URL from domain 2 in domain 1 using `window.open` JavaScript tag and after the user does some staff on domain 2 then put the result in a div on domain 1 using `window.opener`
everything works fine but at the final step, I get cross-origin error `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin.` in chrome console.

How to allow access to a cross-origin on domain 1 in PHP?

**EDIT**

My question is not a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) because I'm asking about PHP.

**SOLUTION**

Just add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` at the beginning of your code after opening PHP tag, this will allow access from any origin (website).

if you want to limit the access, replace `*` with origin (website) url like `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com/");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks where i have to add it? in domain 1 or domain 2?

Comment: I added your code in domain 1 and still giving same error